# Mongoose FindOneAndUpdate only does findOne

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to run a findOneAndUpdate query with my mongoose model, but my document is not updated, so I activated debug mode on mongoose requests and whenever I run the request, the debugs shows that it only runs a findOne request

Here is my updateData function, the model is automatically identified, i've checked filters and data and they contains something

```
async updateData(tableName, filters, data) {
        let res
        if (!filters || isEmpty(filters)) return {sucess: false, message: "Please apply filters for table " + tableName}
        let table = getModel(tableName)
        await table.findOneAndUpdate(filters, data, {upsert: false})
            .then(() => {
                res = {sucess: true, message: "Update sucessfull"}
            })
            .catch((err) => res = {sucess: false, message: "An error occured while updating your data. Error is : " + err})
        return res
    }
```

Here is the debug

```
filters =  { username: 'lolilol' }
data =  {"username": "test"}
Mongoose: user.findOne({ username: 'lolilol' }, { upsert: false, projection: {} })
```

do you have any idea on what I'm missing ? Thanks

Comment: `findOneAndUpdate` returns the updated document when used with `await` operator (your code is in an async function). And, you are using `then` and `catch` - thats mixing Promises syntax with async-await.

Comment: Should I use `then` and `catch` without using `await` for the mongoose functions ? And why is it a bad practice ?

Comment: I think you can use the `await` operator - as the code is within the async function. See this document on using [promises, callbacks and async-await with NodeJS driver APIs](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/promises/).

Comment: I'll try this out, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I see {upsert: false} so maybe your filter is not matching any record.

Comment: But I don't want it to create a new file if it does not found any

Comment: Here is the result without upsert: false `Mongoose: user.findOne({ username: 'lolilol' }, { projection: {} })`